# Adding Ports to Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Can someone please let me know if its possible to allow all services in an inbound nat rule. For example, in the image I would like to allow all services with the symbol * to allow all services in the inboundnat rule rather than having to specify the actual service e.g. 443, 801. etc..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone please let me know if its possible to allow all services
>   in an inbound nat rule.

For now, Azure does **not** support this, we should specify the port number(value must be a vaild number) in NAT rule.

[image]

=====================================================

Update:

If you want to connect this VM, as a workaround, we can associate a public IP address to this VM(which behind a LB).

Comment: Please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: No further help required.